# How to calculate integer based on byte sequence

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, hex

So, I'm trying to understand the math involved when trying to translate hexadecimal escape sequences into integers.

So if I have the string "Ã", when I do `"Ã".encode('utf-8')` I get a byte string like this `"\xc3"`. `ord("Ã")` is 195. The math is 16*12+3 which is 195. Things makes sense.

But if I have the character "é" - then the utf8-encoded hex escape sequence is `"\xc3\xa9` - and `ord("é")` is 233. How is this calculation performed? (a9 on its own is 169 so it's clearly not addition).

Similarly with this `'Ĭ'.encode('utf-8')`. This yields `b'\xc4\xac'`. And `ord('Ĭ')` is 300.

Can anyone explain the math involved here?

Comment: FYI, the byte string of `"Ã".encode('utf-8')` is `b'\xc3\x83'`, not `"\xc3"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 was designed according to a few general design principles / constraints. It is important to understand these design principles in order to understand why the encoding algorithm of UTF-8 is what it is.

1. Backwards-compatibility with ASCII: every ASCII character should have the same encoding in ASCII and UTF-8.
2. Detectability of non-ASCII characters: no octet that would be a valid encoding of an ASCII character should appear in the multi-octet encoding sequence of a non-ASCII character.
3. Length encoding: the length of a multi-octet encoding sequence should be encoded in the first octet, so that we know before reading the entire multi-octet encoding sequence how long it will be. Also, it is easy for a human to determine the length of the multi-octet encoding sequence.
4. Fallback / auto detection: text that is in one of the popular 8-bit encodings (e.g. ISO8859-15, Windows-1252) is *highly* unlikely to contain sequences that are valid UTF-8 multi-octet encoding sequences, therefore such encodings can be easily detected and vice versa.
5. Self-synchronizing: you can start decoding anywhere in the middle of a UTF-8 stream, and it will take you at most until the next ASCII character or start of the next multi-octet encoding sequence to be able to start decoding valid characters. If you can navigate backwards in the stream, it will take backing up at most 3 octets to find a valid start point.
6. Sorting order: sorting UTF-8 streams by octets will automatically yield a sort order by codepoints without having to decode the stream.

The way UTF-8 encoding works is like this:

- Any ASCII character is encoded the same way as in ASCII, as a single octet starting with a `0` bit.
- Any non-ASCII character is encoded as a multi-octet sequence.
- The first octet of the multi-octet encoding sequence starts with the bit pattern `110`, `1110`, or `11110`, where the number of `1` bits denotes the length of the multi-octet sequence, i.e. a multi-octet sequence starting with the octet `1110xxxx` is 3 octets long.
- Any further octet that is part of a multi-octet sequence starts with the bit pattern `10`.
- The Unicode code point is encoded into the non-fixed bits of the multi-octet encoding sequence.

Here is an example: `A` has the Unicode code point U+0041. Since it is an ASCII character, it will simply be encoded the same way as in ASCII, i.e. as binary `01000001`.

The Euro sign `€` has the Unicode code point U+20AC. Since it is not an ASCII character, it needs to be encoded as a multi-octet encoding sequence. Hexadecimal 0x20AC in binary is 10000010101100, so it requires 14 bits to represent.

A two-octet sequence looks like this: `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`, so it gives us only 11 bits. Therefore, we need a three-octet sequence, which looks like this: `1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`. This gives us 16 bits, which is more than we need. The zero-extended binary representation of the code point now simply gets packed into the `x`es:

```
11100010 10000010 10101100
^^^^00xx ^^xxxxxx ^^xxxxxx
```

The hexadecimal representation of this bitstring is `0xE2 0x82 0xAC`.

Note: it would be possible to encode this also as a four-octet sequence, by zero-extending the code point even further. This is called an *overlong encoding* and is not allowed by the UTF-8 specification. Encodings must be as short as possible.

There is an encoding called *Modified UTF-8* which encodes ASCII NUL not as ASCII but as an *overlong* multi-octet sequence. That way, a MUTF-8 string can contain ASCII NUL characters without ever containing a `0x00` null octet and can thus be processed by environments which expect strings to be null-terminated.

Comment: Thank you for this insanely awesome explanation! That really made a lot of pieces add up.

Answer (score 2):

From the doc:

> ord(c)
>
> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an
>   integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For
>   example, ord('a') returns the integer 97 and ord('€') (Euro sign)
>   returns 8364. This is the inverse of chr().

What `ord` returns is the Unicode code point of the character - roughly, a number letting you identify the character among the large number of characters known in Unicode.

When you encode your character with UTF-8, your represent it by a sequence of bytes, which is not directly related to the Unicode code point. There can be some coincidences, mainly for ASCII characters that get represented with a sequence of one byte, but this will fail for all more 'exotic' characters.

Have a look at [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and [the wikipedia page about UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII-encoding of `"é"` is `0xe9`, which is equal to 233 in decimal base.

Sample code for your convenience:

```
for n in range(256):
    print(n,hex(n),chr(n))
```

Comment: Tnx for the reply. I edited the question as I think the answer doesn't fit my question.

Comment: @jlaur: Your edited question yields the exact same issue. When you do `ord('Ĭ')`, it is **the ASCII encoding** of `Ĭ` which is used as input to the `ord` function, **not the utf8 encoding**.

Comment: "é" and "Ĭ" are not defined in ASCII. These numbers are the Unicode code points. For code points below 256, these are the same as Latin 1, which is sometimes referred to as "extended ASCII".

Answer (score 0):

So, I thought I'd just wrap this one up and post the answers to the math issues I didn't comprehend before receiving a tons of wisdom from SO.

The first question regarded "é" which yields `"\xc3\xa9"` when encoded with utf8 and where `ord("é")` returns `233`. Clearly 233 was not the sum of 195 (decimal representation of c3) and 169 (ditto for a9). So what's going on?

"é" is has the corresponding unicode point `U+00E9`. The decimal value for the hex `e9` is 233. So that's what the `ord("é")` is all about.

So how does this end up as `"\xc3\xa9"`?

As Jörg W Mittag explained and demonstrated, in utf8 all non-ASCII are *"encoded as a multi-octet sequence"*.

The binary representation of 233 is `11101001`. As this is non-ASCII this needs to be packed in a two-octet sequence which according to Jörg will follow this pattern:

`110xxxxx 10xxxxxx` (110 and 10 are fixed leaving room for five bits in the first octet, and six bits in the second - 11 in total).

So the 8 bits binary representation of 233 is fitted into this pattern replacing the xx-parts... Since there are 11 bits available and we only need 8 bits we pad the 8 bits with 3 more, `000`, (i.e. `00011101001`).

`^^^00011 ^^101001` (`000` followed by our 8 bits representation of 233)

`11000011 10101001` (binary representation of 233 inserted in a two-octet sequence)

`11000011` equals the hex `c3`, as `10101001` equals `a9`- which in other words matches the original sequence `"\xc3\xa9"`

A similar walkthrough for the character "Ĭ":

`'Ĭ'.encode('utf-8')` yields `b'\xc4\xac'`. And `ord('Ĭ')` is 300.

So again the unicode point for this character is `U+012C` which has the decimal value of 300 ((1*16*16)+(2*16*1)+(12*1)) - so that's the ord-part.

Again the binary representation of 300 is 9 bits, `100101100`. So once more there's a need for a two-octet sequence of the pattern `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`. And again we pad it with a couple of `0` so reach 11 bits (`00100101100`).

`^^^00100 ^^101100` (`00` followed by our 9 bits representation of 300)

`11000100 10101100` (binary representation of 300 inserted in a two octet-sequence).

`11000100` corresponds to `c4`in hex, `10101100` to `ac` - in other words `b'\xc4\xac'`.

Thank you everyone for helping out on this. I learned a lot.